# Google Forms / Spreadsheet converting Thai numerals to Western Arabic numerals

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form with a drop down box containing Thai numbers (single/ double digit) and another drop down box with years (4 digit Thai numbers). On form submit the spreadsheet shows the numbers as Western Arabic numerals (English numbers).

I have tried changing the local of the spreadsheet but it had no effect.

Thai ๐  ๑   ๒   ๓   ๔   ๕   ๖   ๗   ๘   ๙   ๑๐

W A  0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

Comment: All I can do is guess, but the language preference may need to be changed in the user account.  Of course, that would probably affect all Google products.  But I really don't know anything about this.  If it's a user setting, then this isn't a programming question, and might be better in the [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs) or [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SandyGood I tried changing to defaults of the spreadsheet and my account, neither had any effect. It's not a programming question, but it looks like it is going to require a program to solve. I asked in the [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/PHW7b02Ng3k/5ewT61BqAQAJ) and quickly realised I was wasting my time there.

Comment: If your only option is to convert the digits immediately after they are saved, then you could write a function to do that.  You could create an object literal that maps western numbers to Thai numbers:  `var objWesternToThai = {"0":๐,"1":๑};`  Then you would need to get all the data just written to the sheet, have the code loop though all the data, convert the numbers and write the data back.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps apply a series of SUBSTITUTES, for example with `2013` in A1:

```
=substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(A1,0,"๐"),1,"๑"),2,"๒"),3,"๓")
```

returns `๒๐๑๓`